Extracting single file from split zip archive
Lets imagine I have a large amount of data and it will not fit on one single hard drive. I can use a multi part zip archive to split the files into multiple archives, this technique is shown in the man page of zip:

One  use of split archives is storing a large archive on multiple removable media.  For a split archive with 20 split files the files are typically named (replace ARCHIVE with the name of your archive) ARCHIVE.z01, ARCHIVE.z02, ..., ARCHIVE.z19, ARCHIVE.zip.  Note that the last file is the .zip  file.   In contrast,  spanned archives are the original multi-disk archive generally requiring floppy disks and using volume labels to store disk numbers. zip supports split archives but not spanned archives, though a procedure exists for converting split archives of the right size to spanned  archives.   The  reverse is also true, where each file of a spanned archive can be copied in order to files with the above names to create a split archive.

Now I would like to restore some files from the zip archive. For this I need to read the index file in ARCHIVE.zip which lists all the containing files using zip -l archive.zip. How do I know in which archive the file is stored? Lets say the file that I would like to store is in archive.z03.How can I extract the file from archive.z03 without transfering all the files back, concatinating everything into a single zip file and extracting it?
For simplicity the files are stored without compression, so I guess they should be able to be read directly.
For creating the zip archives for testing: zip -r -s 500M -0 archive.zip /path/to/files
I don't know much about files and filesystems. But since the files are uncompressed, I think the zip file is just a concatenation of the individual files. So it should be possible to read the file manually directly.

Just so you're aware, the request for a newer zip utility is explicitly off topic on Superuser. I recommend that you remove that part of the question and focus on "how do I do this".
